# jQuery typewriter into placeholder element

Tags: jquery, dom

Having some problems, trying to insert a string into the placeholder element on an HTML form. 
Declared a variable to use for parameter in each function, not sure if this is the correct way ...

```
var placeholder_value = $(search-typing).prop('placeholder');
```

Little experience with jQuery, can someone please assist

http://jsbin.com/araget/306/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's a typo, but search-typing isn't a variable name: variables can't have a dash/minus in them.  You'd need a variable like search_typing.

There's a great post [What characters are valid for JavaScript variable names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/valid-characters-for-javascript-variable-names) on this.

Comment: 'search-typing' is the ID attribute on the form that I'm trying to get value of

Comment: This is what you need then: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/

Comment: Yep, rgin is right, b/c then you'll have $('#search-typing') instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
var placeholder_value = $('#search-typing').prop('placeholder');
```

You need to use a proper prefix on your selector, Use a # to get an element by its id. Use a period to get an element (or elements) by class - i.e:

```
$('.myClass').prop('placeholder');
```

You also need to enclose it in quotes as above.

This is pretty good interactive way to learn the basics behind jQuery

https://www.codeschool.com/courses/try-jquery